# Cannot run ZapProxy add_header_request.py - throwable exception

Tags: zap

I am dropping this
https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/main/httpsender/add_header_request.py  into ZAP scripts window > Proxy

When I save and browse a site, I see `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException`

I expected to see additional headers as in sample script above - can anyone help?

I am new to Zap scripting, after having a good hunt, I can find little on how this lang interfaces with Zap or any docs on it

I am on Windows.

Comment: We might need the full error or output, but this looks more like a Zap support issue than a security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks from what you are saying that you've added this as a `proxy` script.
Thats not right, its an `httpsender` script, so you need to add it as one of those.

Comment: Thanks - that helped! I also discovered your vid on them with the templates - so I was able to get it running - thank you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ujL6rH6nVXI I used the template and changed for my needs under the HTTP Sender in the script tree.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Security.SE. I flagged this answer as I guess it should be a comment to @Simon Bennetts' answer. If it did help, perhaps you could mark their answer as "accepted" to help others that would have the same issue.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/181360)